# Is there an easier way to select specific parts of a column?

Tags: sql

I am working on homework for class and one of the questions is:

Create a query that will show the item id, size, max and min price for all those items that have a size of Large, Extra 
Large or Extra Extra Large.  Before writing this query make sure you know how the size data is stored.  Sort your output by size.

I tried this way, but it had XXXL so I couldn't use it:

```
select itemid,
       size,
       maxprice,
       minprice
from   item
where  size like  'L' 
       or size like '%xl'
order by size
```

Then I tried this way and got the results I needed, but I feel like this is a lazy way for some reason and a little to long:

```
select itemid,
       size,
       maxprice,
       minprice
from   item
where  size like  'L' 
       or size like 'xl' 
       or size like 'xxl'
order by size
```

So is there a way I can make the query simpler and select what I'm looking for or no?

Answer (score 3):

Using `IN` clause:

```
SELECT itemid, size, maxprice, minprice
FROM item
WHERE size IN  ('L' , 'XL', 'XXL')
ORDER BY size;
```

Comment: Thank you :) I believe we will be learning about "in" clauses next week :P